# SSIS - Derived Columns - Case Statment - Charindex and Substring

Tags: sql-server, ssis, substring, charindex, derived-column

I've the fololwing transformation in T-SQL:

```
SELECT [FIELD_A] = case when CHARINDEX('-', FIELD_B)>0 then LEFT(FIELD_B,CHARINDEX('-', FIELD_B)-1)
    else FIELD_B end,
```

How can I put this into a expression in Derived Column object using SQL Server Integration Services 2014?

Regards!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derived Column transformations use SSIS Expression syntax.  The syntax for this would work something like this:

```
FINDSTRING(FIELD_B, "-", 1) > 0 ? LEFT(FIELD_B, FINDSTRING(FIELD_B, "-", 1)-1) : FIELD_B
```

I haven't tested it, but it should get you going down the right path.  To walk through it:

- FINDSTRING takes 3 values - what text you want to search in, what text you want to search for, and which occurrence you want to find.
- The "If" logic in SSIS expressions is the ? and : symbols.  The ? follows the "If" boolean expression, and the : separates the "If true" and "If False" expressions.
- Literal strings in SSIS Expressions need double-quotes around them.

Findstring reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/findstring-ssis-expression

Conditional reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression